# mmap() causing segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, valgrind, mmap

I'm pretty sure my mistake is very evident, but I just can't seem to find where the problem is.

I'm learning how to use `mmap()` in C, everything looks correct to me, but I get a segmentation fault.

Here is my code:

```
int n=50;
char * tab = mmap(NULL, n, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   tab[i] = 1;
}
```

Using `valgrind`, I get an error saying "Invalid write of size 1" at the line where I do `tab[i]=1`, (I have tried replacing `1` by `'1'` thinking that maybe a char has a smaller size than an `int`, but still get the same error), followed by "Address `0xfffff..ff` is not stack'd, malloc'd, or (recently) free'd".

I have no idea where my mistake is. Can somebody help me find it?

Comment: *I have no idea where my mistake is? Please help!*  You're not checking the value returned from `mmap()` to ensure the call actually worked.

Comment: @AndrewHenle by doing `printf("%p", tab)` I get 0xfff..fff.

Comment: This is `MAP_FAILED` value `errno` is set to indicate the issue

Comment: Oh! Ok, thank you. Why is the mmap failing?

Comment: `explain_errno_mmap` can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man 2 mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> The contents of a file mapping (as opposed to an anonymous mapping;
>          see `MAP_ANONYMOUS` below), are initialized using `length` bytes starting
>          at offset `offset` in the file (or other object) referred to by the
>          file descriptor `fd`.

I suppose that you are trying to create an anonymous mapping (i.e. not backed by a file). In such case, you *need* to add `MAP_ANONYMOUS` to the `flags`, otherwise the system will try to read from the specified `fd`, which is invalid (`-1`) and will fail.

The correct code is:

```
char *tab = mmap(NULL, n, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
if (tab == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(1);
}
```

---

For the future, note that you can easily detect the error like I did above with a simple call to [`perror()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) in case the returned value indicates failure. In your case it should have printed the following:

```
mmap: Bad file descriptor
```

Checking the manual again you can see in the "ERRORS" section:

> **EBADF**:  `fd` is not a valid file descriptor (and `MAP_ANONYMOUS` was not set).